# How to segment user specific data using HTML5 Local Storage?

Tags: html, local-storage

I am building a web app, where there is a lot of user specific data. Prior to HTML5, I would have just saved all this data in a database on the server.

Eg: Username, List of books read.

With HTML5 Local storage, I imagine I could just store it on the client. The problem is, what if there are multiple users using the same client (computer & web browser).

Is there a way to separate the user data for each user in local storage ? Is this not what HTML5 Local Storage was intended for ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In most cases you should clear the localStorage for each user for privacy reasons.

However, if the data is generic, non-identifiable data, something simple like a high score from a game, then yes a object based storage *might* be ok.

If the data is anything specific, or identifiable, deleting the localStorage after a timeout, logout, or login is preferred.

Clear the localStorage:

```
localStorage.clear();
```

and start fresh after one of the above events.

Otherwise a web-savvy person could view the browser's localStorage content and each user's data.

Answer (score 0):

Store an array of 'users' object.  Html 5 Local Storage is quite flexible. You can then search for the object using an id for example.